# MFC .exe and .dll produce different resuls for same code

Tags: c++, delphi, visual-studio-2008, dll, mfc

I faced following issue with my work: having two projects: MFC .dll and MFC .exe based on same source code (except entry points of course), I observe different results produced by them when processing same data. I have checked all projects settings for both and found all project properties similar (at least those I think are important). After running several tests I learned following:

1. MFC .exe produces same results on same dataset in both 'Debug' and 'Release' modes
2. MFC .dll produces **Different** results on same dataset for 'Debug' and 'Release' modes
3. .dll's 'Release' results don't match with .dll's 'Debug' results nor with any of .exe's 'Debug' or 'Release' results.

I suppose .exe works correctly just because it gives same results for both compiler configurations, but I can't check this for sure. So, how this issure with .dll 'Release' configuration can be resolved? I mean, how can I force it coincide with others? What does explain such behaviour?

**Edit**

I guess problem occurs because I use host application written on Delphi. I even created new C++ exe to test this suggestion and saw it worked normal, without any mistakes. Only difference is that creating DLL to be used in Delphi application I marked it **extern "C"**, but for C++ application I wrote just **extern**. Details of another discussion on this topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933998/problems-with-postmessage-from-c-dll-to-delphi-forms-application/10938781#10938781). But if try to use DLL with only **extern** mark, without **"C"**, my Delphi application reports that function entry point couldn't be located there... It is a big question for me now why this happens... Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by results? Please post some code and the actual output.

Comment: You don't debug code by tinkering with the project settings.  Use a debugger.

Comment: Well, there's a lot of code actually - maybe 15 files or so, I suppose this will be little hard to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the values of the 8087 Control Word for each of the hosts. I'm pretty sure that the Microsoft C uses a different value to that which Delphi uses. In the more recent Delphi versions, you have functions such as Set8087CW and the wrappers like SetPrecisionMode and SetRoundMode. But you will probably want to set them specifically in your DLL, and then restore them to the original at the end of your calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try check it. BTW I used to encountered some problems with 8087 preprocessor in old TURBO PASCAL compilers but I thought they already disappeared by this time. OK, thank you, I'll tell if it helps.

Comment: While searching documentation on methods you proposed I discovered another approach: to set CLR support (that wasn't set before). Now it works good.

Comment: @Rail Write an answer with your solution, and accept it. Better to have the answer formally recognised.

Comment: Well, this didn't help to solve the problem, so I discarded this method. Adding Set8087CW($027F) to Delphi code currently solves an issue for observed tests.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this without some code examples. But one thing to consider is whether your data processing code uses global data structures that are also used by the code that calls the processor.

Dll's create their own separate address space and may access a different set of global data structures by default.

Suppose you have a global table that you use to tabulate results that is used in the main code, and the processing code.

In the version that is all in one exe they will both use the same table. In the dll version, the processing dll will use one set of globals, and the exe that links to it is using a different version.